# Failed to download any source lists! (node.js v10.7.0 | yarn 1.7.0 | react-native: 0.56.0 | Windows 10)

Tags: react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I am trying to run a hello world application using the steps clarified [hear](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). I am pretty sure I have done all the steps. but when I try to `react-native run-android` I get the below error.

[react-native run-android ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bjuo.png)

```
C:\Users\Mike-laptop\AwesomeProject>react-native run-android
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users\Mike-laptop\AwesomeProject\node_modules (43ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\Mike-laptop\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

Failed to download any source lists!
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.3

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.602 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

**Please note that I am running everything behind proxy... it is most likely due to the fact that react-native is not using proxy I have setup.** I have tried to configure things in different ways.

- Internet options
- yarn config set proxy http://host:port
- yarn config set h t t p s-proxy h t t p://host:port
- npm config set proxy h t t p://host:port
- npm config set h t t p s-proxy h t t p://host:port
- set environment variable

  set h t t p s_proxy=h t t p s://127.0.0.1:8123 
  set h t t p _proxy=h t t p://127.0.0.1:8123
  set proxy=h t t p://127.0.0.1:8123

Still no luck :(

Much appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to configure your Android env to run Android apps.

Please, take the steps in this link, in the `Building Projects with Native Code` tab, choose Windows and Android.:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Make sure you install Android SDK build tools 26.0.3 inside Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the response ... I installed `Build Tools revision 26.0.3` and now complains about `Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-26`

Comment: I don't understand why it needs android-26 cuz on the page it says you need android-23 which I already installed.

Comment: Re: `Failed to download any source lists!` I am using SSH tunnel as proxy and then I use polipo to convert socks to http proxy. Then I use internet options and I use local ip address as proxy but for some reason it is not working. (if I  use IE it complains it can't connect to the proxy server.) I can't find any solution for that either.